# Webvantage vs. Redmine

Tags: redmine, software

If you have familiarity with both [Webvantage](http://gotoadvantage.com/) and [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), where do they overlap?  Where do they compliment each other?  Which do you prefer overall, and which features do you prefer of either?  Do you have a workflow that uses them both?

Comment: What is the point of comparison really? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: We have an internal company dialogue about it, and I'm looking to add more complete information and other points of view.  We're using Webvantage for project management, and want little-to-no overlap in functionality.  Webvantage does not have version control currently, but that may be on the horizon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all redmine is free and written in ruby - we can change anytime we want -, but has no real support. It can be integrated with different version control systems, but frankly I have never used this particular feature.

Honestly, I've never used webvantage, but I was unable to find any usable information about it in 10 minutes, so this means something to me. I'm using redmine for almost 6 months now, and it is the best tool I had used in the last 7 years. It has it's problems, but it is flexible, reporting and issue handling is in one place etc. If you have any specific question please let me know so that I can answer your question more precisely.

Comment: kudos for "but I was unable to find any usable information about it in 10 minutes, so this means something to me." :D