# Activity report software/web application

Tags: pm-software, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What time tracking / time management software do you use?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-time-tracking-time-management-software-do-you-use)

Do you know/use any 'activity report' software? I mean an application, where employees sign in, and report how many hours they worked every day in a month (possibly also a description of what exactly have they done, or a list of tasks completed)?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-time-tracking-time-management-software-do-you-use ?

Answer (score 2):

We use [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) from Attlasian. You can assign work hour estimates per task. 
Developers can burndown the hours for a task, an you can see which task took longer as planned.
So this is a: "Jack worked 4 hours in Issue TEST-13, TEST-13 now has 5 hours remaing estimate"
kind of report.

There is also the "activies" view, wich is more like a blog roll of everything that happened in the project. 
So more of a. "Jack stopped working on TEST-13. Jack closed TEST-12 with a comment 'works for me'" mind of report.

In our Team, we don't use the hour estimates, but whenever I was away for a day I allways look at the "activities"to see what has been going on. This is no replacement for talking to the team of course, but it helps me framing some questions.

Answer (score 1):

I used **redmine**: https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/4208/468

Answer (score 0):

Anuko [Time Tracker](https://timetracker.anuko.com/) - fast, easy, usable